# can an XL macro select a range with variable starting and ending rows?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, row

I'm a front-line tech.  Not new to macro coding, but most of my experience is in WordPerfect macros.  I'm trying to code an Excel macro which will select and act on a range in a series of files.  The desired range is in a constant set of columns, but a variable set of rows.  Static values mark the starting and ending rows, but those rows will vary with each data file.

The problem I'm having is that when I record a macro, XL does not record my cursor movements (Ctrl-Up, Ctrl-Shift-Home, etc), it records the absolute cell addresses I am acting upon.  Since the starting and ending rows will vary with each data file, absolute cell references will not work.  Can anyone provide any hints as to how I could/should approach this?

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim rng as Range

With ActiveSheet
    'Ctrl+Arrow
    Set rng = .Range("A10000").End(xlUp) 'CTRL+Up arrow
    Set rng = .Range("A1").End(xlDown) 'CTRL+Down arrow
    Set rng = .Range("Z1").End(xlToLeft) 'CTRL+Left arrow
    Set rng = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight) 'CTRL+Right arrow

    'Ctrl+Shift+Arrow
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1"),.Range("A1").End(xlDown)) 
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1"),.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))

End With
```

Comment: awesome!  Thanks Tim, you rock!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Tim's answer is perfectly concise - Another cool thing you should know about is recording a macro with relative references - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213740

Your challenge is that when you record a macro, it defaults to Absolute Referencing, if you push the relative reference button, you will get the result you were looking for.

Hope this helps too!

Comment: Thanks John, also very helpful!  definitely needed this info.